# Random modify state after animation completion

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui

I'd like to be able to change the state of a variable once an animation is complete and then redraw using the new value.

For example, in the code below, I'd like the Text to rotate a *different* amount each time the animation cycle completes.

```
struct RotateView: View {
    @State var angle: CGFloat = 0
    var body: some View {
        Text("Rotate")
            .rotationEffect(Angle.degrees(angle))
            .onAppear {
                withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 2).repeatForever()) {
                    self.angle = CGFloat.random(in: -360 ... 360)
                }
            }
    }
}

struct RotateView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        RotateView()
    }
}
```

I understand that within the `withAnimation` body closure that I'm only setting the state to animate between and this is only executed once - thus, a random amount is calculated and the text rotates that amount forever.

I've looked at [this](https://www.avanderlee.com/swiftui/withanimation-completion-callback/) excellent post that adds an `onAnimationCompleted` but it seems like overkill for my problem. In addition, while it sort of worked, the callback was called *many* times after each animation completed and randomly set the variable many times - causing the `Text` to rotate very quickly until the animation kicked off again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you can stick to the defined duration of 2 secs, you can combine the .onAppear animation with additional animations kicked off by a timer that fires every two seconds.

```
    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 2, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    
    @State var angle: CGFloat = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Rotate")
            .rotationEffect(Angle.degrees(angle))
            .onAppear {
                withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 2)) {
                    self.angle = CGFloat.random(in: -360 ... 360)
                }
            }
            .onReceive(timer) { time in
                withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 2)) {
                    self.angle = CGFloat.random(in: -360 ... 360)
                }
            }
    }
```